# Pivoting Nominal Data in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R that I need to manipulate (pivot).  At the simplest level the first few rows would look like the following:

```
Batch  Unit  Success InputGrouping
1       1     1       A
2       5     1       B
3       4     0       C
1       1     1       D
2       5     1       A
```

I would like to pivot this data so that the column names would be InputGrouping and the values would be 1 if it exists and 0 if not.  Using above:

```
Batch  Unit  Success  A   B  C  D
1       1     1       1   0  0  1
2       5     1       1   1  0  0
3       4     0       0   0  1  0
```

I've looked at reshape/cast but can't figure out if this transformation is possible with the package.  Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is indeed possible using `reshape2` with the function `dcast()`.

Recreate your data:

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
Batch  Unit  Success InputGrouping
1       1     1       A
2       5     1       B
3       4     0       C
1       1     1       D
2       5     1       A")
```

Now recast the data:

```
library("reshape2")

dcast(Batch + Unit + Success ~ InputGrouping, data=dat, fun.aggregate = length)
```

The results:

```
Using InputGrouping as value column: use value.var to override.
  Batch Unit Success A B C D
1     1    1       1 1 0 0 1
2     2    5       1 1 1 0 0
3     3    4       0 0 0 1 0
```

Comment: Worked perfect, thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a possible solution using the `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, as.list(table(InputGrouping)), by = .(Batch, Unit, Success)]
#    Batch Unit Success A B C D
# 1:     1    1       1 1 0 0 1
# 2:     2    5       1 1 1 0 0
# 3:     3    4       0 0 0 1 0
```